# PGSql No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, im in migrating database from Oracle to PGSql project, and now im fixing some query.
i've got an error like this :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function nvl(timestamp without time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

and i've found that nvl error from console on this string builder

```
    public List<InsEmployeeInfoVo> load(int first, int pageSize,
            String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, SearchFilter searchFilter) {
        SQLQuery query = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
            sqlQuery.append(" select ");
            sqlQuery.append("     pts.PERSON_TRAN_SING_ID, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     ext.INTERNALID PERSON_EXT_ID, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     people.internalid PERSON_ID, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     people.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER NIK, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     people.PER_INFORMATION1 PERSON_NAME, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     case ");
            sqlQuery.append("         when pts.INS_MEMBER_NO is not null ");
            sqlQuery.append("         then pts.INS_MEMBER_NO ");
            sqlQuery.append("         else ext.INS_MEMBER_NO ");
            sqlQuery.append("     end INS_MEMBER_NO, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     case ");
            sqlQuery.append("         when pts.INS_TOTAL_COVER is not null ");
            sqlQuery.append("         then pts.INS_TOTAL_COVER ");
            sqlQuery.append("         else ext.INS_TOTAL_COVER ");
            sqlQuery.append("     end INS_TOTAL_COVER, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     null INS_PLAN_NAME, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     case ");
            sqlQuery.append("         when pts.INS_BH_CARD_NO is not null ");
            sqlQuery.append("         then pts.INS_BH_CARD_NO ");
            sqlQuery.append("         else ext.INS_BH_CARD_NO ");
            sqlQuery.append("     end INS_BH_CARD_NO, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     case ");
            sqlQuery.append("         when pts.INS_BH_TOTAL_COVER is not null ");
            sqlQuery.append("         then pts.INS_BH_TOTAL_COVER ");
            sqlQuery.append("         else ext.INS_BH_TOTAL_COVER ");
            sqlQuery.append("     end INS_BH_TOTAL_COVER, ");
            sqlQuery.append("   null INS_BH_PLAN_NAME, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     pts.PROCESS_STATUS PROCESS_STATUS, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     BTPN_INS_F_GET_CHECKER (people.internalid,:singSourceType,1) PROCESS_STATUS_NAME, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     pts2.PERSON_TRAN_SING_ID PERSON_TRAN_SING_ID_2, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     pts2.PROCESS_STATUS PROCESS_STATUS_2, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     upl.PERSON_DATA_UPL_DTL_ID, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     upl.PROCESS_STATUS PROCESS_STATUS_UPLOAD, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     NVL(pts.UPDATE_ON, pts.CREATE_ON) INPUT_DATE, ");
            sqlQuery.append("     BTPN_INS_F_GET_CHECKER (people.internalid,:singSourceType,2) NOTE_APPROVE, pts.NOTE ");
            sqlQuery.append(" from WOT_PEOPLE people ");
            sqlQuery.append("     inner join WOT_ASSIGNMENT assign ");
            sqlQuery.append("         on assign.PERSON_ID = people.internalid ");
            sqlQuery.append("         and assign.PRIMARY_FLAG = 'Y' ");
            sqlQuery.append("         and (date_trunc('day', now()) between assign.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and assign.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) ");
            sqlQuery.append("     left join BTPN_INS_PEOPLE_EXT ext ");
            sqlQuery.append("         on ext.PERSON_ID = people.internalid ");
            sqlQuery.append("         and date_trunc('day', now()) between ext.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and NVL(ext.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE, now()) ");
```

i think something wrong with the last NVL variable but im not sure, im not usually use this native query and im new in PGSql too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use PostgreSQL `COALESCE` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-conditional.html) (see the *9.17.2. COALESCE* section) instead of oracle `NVL` [function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm).

Comment: . . `COALESCE()` is not a "Postgres" function.  It is standard SQL and I recommend using it in all databases, including Oracle.

Comment: i just find NVL & replace to COALESCE , and it works! thanks :)